# how do I operate on (I-AB)^(-1)

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to prove:

Let $A$,$B$ be $n \times n$ matrices. Prove:

If there exists, $(I-AB)^{-1}$ then there exists $(I-BA)^{-1}$.

Furthermore, $(I-BA)^{-1}= I+B(I-AB)^{-1}A$

I don't know how to operate on $(I-AB)^{-1}$ to begin the proof.

Comment: This theorem is made much easier using the [theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester's_determinant_theorem)
$$
\det(I - AB) = \det(I - BA)
$$

Answer (score 3):

We have

$$(I-BA)(I+B(I-AB)^{-1}A)=I-BA+B(I-AB)^{-1}A-BAB(I-AB)^{-1}A$$

and

$$BAB(I-AB)^{-1}A=B(AB-I+I)(I-AB)^{-1}A=-BA+B(I-AB)^{-1}A$$
so

$$(I-BA)(I+B(I-AB)^{-1}A)=I$$
and we conclude.

Comment: Thank you. It took some effort to find that:

Comment: Thank you. It took some effort to find: -BA[B(I-BA)^(-1)]A = -BA + B[I-AB)^(-1)]A. Is this a standard problem? Did it occur to you out of nowhere? If out of nowhere, I am impressed by your math skills.